# Serial communication between QEMU host and guest

Tags: serial-port, virtual-machine, communication, qemu, socat

I'm trying to set up a pair of serial ports between my QEMU host (Debian Jessie x86_64) and guest (also Debian Jessie, but on ARM). Everything except the serial port part works.

I'm really new to QEMU so there might be a better way but I've tested the following flags when running QEMU:

`-chardev tty,id=mytty,path=/dev/pts/2` (/dev/pts/2 & 3 are up with socat)

`-chardev pty,id=mypty` QEMU opens a PTY but when I try to read or write from host get permission denied.

In either case I can't find the ports in my guest. /dev/pts is empty and in /dev there are only tty and ttyAMA3. So, my problem is setting up communication in general and I'm especially curious on where the ports are on my guest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question. First the device tree was incomplete so I needed to add 3 additional  uart ports. That's the reason I could not find my ports in the guest.

Second, I needed to tell QEMU to use on of the ports as stdio: `-append ... console=ttyAMA3` and `-serial mon:stdio`. Then I'm able to, with `-serial pty`, link QEMUs ttyAMA* to pts/* on the host.

Comment: "I needed to add 3 additional uart ports" -- Would you please explain how you did that? or link to a resource that explains this?

Comment: hi, I'm running with -cdrom and -drive options (installing ubuntu on a qemu machine), but I don't know how to see the serial port output. Can you tell me how to do it?